# Rails 3 - how does reject_if work with build?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

Using Rails 3.1 & Ruby 1.9.2.

I have a has_many association between a Question and an Answer model. The question model has this line:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :reject_if => 
        lambda { |n| n[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

---

My view is a little complicated, suffice it to say it returns an array of questions, where each question may have a nested array of between 0 and 5 answers. I am certain this part works fine.

---

In my controller, I run the following code to build and save questions & answers:

```
def create_questions
   params[:question].each do |q|
     new_question = Question.new(q)

     ...

     if q[:answers] != nil # this only solves the problem of 
                           # a question having 0 answers 
       q[:answers].each do |a|
         new_question.answers.build(a)
       end
    end

    new_question.save
  end
end
```

---

My problem is I get answers saved with blank content. I think the `answers.build` is overriding the `reject_if`, but am not sure. I am well aware that there are a million workarounds I can use to solve this problem, but what would be the conventional and shortest (code-wise) way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `accept_nested_attributes_for` method is used for direct feed of nested model's fields. I mean you just need to include the :answers_attributes in the question hash. It should be done in the view itself. But I am not sure how are you handling the view so I am going to replace

```
if q[:answers] != nil # this only solves the problem of a question having 0 answers 
   q[:answers].each do |a|
     new_question.answers.build(a)
   end
end
```

with

```
q[:answers_attributes] = q.delete(:answers)
```

Or you can just change the `:answers` to `:answers_attributes` in your view itself. And remove the conditional part from controller.

**Note** You also need to `answers_attributes` to model's `attr_accessible`.

Comment: Your last line was my solution, thanks. Plus, your suggestion to change the params hash in the controller is creative. I prefer handling this particular issue in view, but it might be useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` handles params automatically.

If in your form you have

```
<%= form_for @question do |f| %>
```

and inside it you have

```
<%= f.fields_for :answers do |f| %>
```

Then the logic for creating the answers when creating the questions is already there. Check that the name of the fields should be similar to `question[][answers_attributes][content]`.

In your controller, you only need to do:

```
new_question = Question.new(q)
```

and that will create the nested questions for you, using the `reject_if` block.

If you create the answers manually, then it's your responsibility to reject the answer as well.

Comment: I tried your suggestion first, but it didn't work. My problem was I did not have `answers_attributes` in my Question model's `attr_accessible`, as @Manjo noted I should. Thanks!